# Git extensions changed line shape

Tags: git-extensions

In the 2.48 version the lines connecting the commits were more curved:

[v2.48](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9A6o.png)

In 2.49 this was changed:

[v2.49](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwj9U.png)

I didn't find any reference to this in the changelogs and I prefer the old style, so maybe someone knows how to revert to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [pull request](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/2662) on github which introduced the change. It is hard-coded, so my question regarding changing is meaningless.